# React Native app crashes when login

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm having troble with my app, this app is react native and everything is works well, but in production it's crashes on login. On Dev mode, on my phone it's okay, only on production crashes.

I tried some solutions that I found here in stackOverflow but none of them helped in fixing the bug.
The first error is a normal firebase connection and get uid for user. I can't fix this and it's a simple connection... help please!!

This is the error:

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: null is not an object (evaluating 'l.currentUser.uid'), stack:
value@306:2672
onPress@306:6430
touchableHandlePress@174:1566
_performSideEffectsForTransition@167:8505
_receiveSignal@167:7292
touchableHandleResponderRelease@167:4757
g@41:296
invokeGuardedCallback@41:496
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError@41:611
A@41:2410
D@41:3172
U@41:2969
<unknown>@41:15497
batchedUpdates@41:72147
Ie@41:14848
ze@41:15343
receiveTouches@41:16180
value@18:3582
<unknown>@18:1067
value@18:3009
value@18:1039

    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
    at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks

Anderson - LógikaWeb

Comment: Although I can't really give a complete answer, but from the error it seems the return value (l.currentUser.uid) is null. Can you try to do a console log to make sure that's the case (either "l" or "l.currentUser")? If it is the case then you can try to search why firebase returns null and start from there.

Comment: This might help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: I changed a route and fix the code error in props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

old version problem!

First the problem it's a empty variable. I changed a route and fix the code error in props. 
I update my ambient and all works fine with 0.61 version.